# Servlet use html file and XMLHttpRequest to display data

Tags: java, servlets

I have created an AJAX endpoint that will supply a front-end AJAX request with a JSON Array of articles. I need assistance displaying the data in an HTML file. The Article class is for an Article object that can represent information from the article's data. In the ArticleListGenerator class, I have a single static method called getArticleList() that will return a list of articles. The getArticleList() method access the JSON file that is used to generate JSON. In my JSONResponse class, I have a single static method that takes a response object and an object that implements the JSONAware interface as arguments. And the Endpoint class is my doGet method. The next thing I want to do is display the data on an HTML page.

In the Html file, I have a javascript and I am using XMLHttpRequest to get the JSON data from the endpoint, servlet class "Endpoint" I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

In my HTML file, I have try javascript

```js
<script>
    var url="/endpoint";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (!xhttp) {
            console.log('Unable to create XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }else if(xhttp.readyState == 4 &&xhttp.status===200) {
            data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            console.log(" test:"+data);
        }else{
            console.log("page not found")
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
    xhttp.send();
</script>
```

I my web.xml file

```html
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Endpoint</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Test.web.Endpoint</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Endpoint</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/endpoint</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

```html
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private int authorId;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAuthorId() {
        return this.authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public static JSONObject toJson(Article a) {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

        if (a != null) {
            jObj.put("id", a.getId());
            jObj.put("title", JSONObject.escape(a.getTitle()));
            jObj.put("content", JSONObject.escape(a.getContent()));
            jObj.put("author_id", a.getAuthorId());
        }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

```html
public class ArticleListGenerator {

    public static List<Article> getArticleList(){

        List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("JSONArray.json"))) {

            Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(inputStreamReader);
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                Article article = new Article();

                String title = (String) jsonObject.get("title");
                Long id = (Long) jsonObject.get("id");
                Long authorId = (Long) jsonObject.get("author_id");
                String content = (String) jsonObject.get("content");

                article.setTitle(title);
                article.setId(id.intValue());
                article.setAuthorId(authorId.intValue());
                article.setContent(content);

                articles.add(article);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return articles;
    }

}
```

```html
public class JSONResponse {
    public static void send(HttpServletResponse response, JSONAware j) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        try {
            response.getWriter().print(j.toJSONString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
public class Endpoint extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Article> article=ArticleListGenerator.getArticleList();
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0; i<article.size();i++){
            jArr.add(Article.toJson(article.get(i)));
        }

        JSONResponse.send(resp, jArr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Please be more specific.

Comment: i am not sure if my javascript code is correct. I need some direction displaying the data .ie passing JSON data to HTML file